# How do I make my async coroutine function not block?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write some concurrent Python.

In my app below, I'm trying to subscribe to a websocket feed, but then continue through the app, so this code should just print `hello`. Instead, it blocks on `feed.__init__`.

I'm hoping I can build a websocket client to some update some application state.

How do I do `feed.__init__` and continue running my program, while the websocket runs in the background?

```
def main():
  myFeed = feed('XBTUSD')
  while True:
    "hello"


import websockets
import asyncio
import json

class feed:
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.uri = "wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=instrument,quote:{}".format(symbol)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.socket())
        # asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
   

    async def socket(self):
      async with websockets.connect(self.uri) as websocket:
        while True: 
          msg = await websocket.recv()
          self.process_msg(json.loads(msg))

    def process_msg(self, msg):
      try:
        data = msg['data'][0]
        if data['symbol'] == self.symbol:
            self.last_message = msg 

      except:
        print("Unhandled")
```

Comment: From my experience with `asyncio`, the issue is you have `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete` in the class. That should be fairly "top-level"; like in a `main` or some place equivalent; then you'd `await` on the actions that need to be waited on. Asyncio operates on one thread though afaik, so you can't have a `while True` also doing work on that same thread. You need to make sure you're allowing other jobs to run. Unless you want each `feed` to operate independently, in which case you'd probably want to have it spawn a thread, and have `asyncio` use the spawned thread.

Comment: Ah, that makes a bit more sense. So to be clear, asyncio does no threading work out of the box?

Comment: No, it simply manages the time of the thread it's started on.